# How to add image compression using PHPicker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Below is my Picker code. It works great, but the full res image is too much -- causing smaller Image views be grainy. How can I add compression to the final result? Thanks!

```
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.filter = .images
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)

            guard let provider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }

            if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
                    self.parent.image = image as? UIImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant resize not compress.

Comment: I mean compress -- unless resize means the same thing. My UIImagePickerController has the below code for compression. I don't know how to implement it for PHPicker. Thanks        


if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.35)!
            }

Comment: I might have just discovered you can configure compression when saving the image (CoreData)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try "jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)"

```
if provider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
    provider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, _ in
        if let uiImage = selectedImage as? UIImage {
            uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
            self.parent.image = uiImage
        }
    }
}
```